# Docker swarm, listening in container but not outside

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-swarm

We have a number docker images running in a swarm-mode and are having trouble getting one of them to listen externally.

If I exec to container I can curl the URL on 0.0.0.0:8080.

When I look at networking on the host I see 1 packet being stuck in `Recv-Q` for this listening port (but not for the others that are working correctly.

Looking at the NAT rules I actually can curl 172.19.0.2:8084 on the docker host (docker_gwbridge) but not on the actual docker-host IP (172.31.105.59).

I've tried a number of different points (7080, 8084, 8085) and also stopped docker, did a rm -rf /var/lib/docker, and then tried only running this container but no luck.  Any ideas on why this wouldn't be working for this one container image but 5 others work fine?

**Docker Service**

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --replicas 1 --network myoverlay \
  --publish 8084:8080 \
  --name containerimage \
  docker.repo.net/containerimage
```

**ss -ltn**

```
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                              Local Address:Port                                                               Peer Address:Port

LISTEN      0      128                                                 172.31.105.59:7946                                                                          *:*
LISTEN      0      128                                                             *:ssh                                                                           *:*
LISTEN      0      128                                                     127.0.0.1:smux                                                                          *:*
LISTEN      0      128                                                 172.31.105.59:2377                                                                          *:*
LISTEN      0      128                                                            :::webcache                                                                     :::*
LISTEN      0      128                                                            :::tproxy                                                                       :::*
LISTEN      0      128                                                            :::us-cli                                                                       :::*
LISTEN      0      128                                                            :::us-srv                                                                       :::*
LISTEN      0      128                                                            :::4243                                                                         :::*
LISTEN      1      128                                                            :::8084                                                                         :::*
LISTEN      0      128                                                            :::ssh                                                                          :::*
LISTEN      0      128                                                            :::cslistener                                                                   :::*
```

**iptables -n  -L  -t nat**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.19.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match src-type LOCAL
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-INGRESS (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8084 to:172.19.0.2:8084
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9000 to:172.19.0.2:9000
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083 to:172.19.0.2:8083
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080 to:172.19.0.2:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8081 to:172.19.0.2:8081
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8082 to:172.19.0.2:8082
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

**ip a | grep 172.19**

```
inet 172.19.0.1/16 scope global docker_gwbridge
```

**ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:d1:da:a7:1d:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.105.59/24 brd 172.31.105.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 3088sec preferred_lft 3088sec
    inet6 fe80::10d1:daff:fea7:1d1a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
    link/ether 02:42:55:ae:ff:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker_gwbridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ce:b5:27:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 scope global docker_gwbridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:ceff:feb5:2749/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
23: vethe2712d7@if22: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP
    link/ether 92:58:81:03:25:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::9058:81ff:fe03:2520/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: vethc446bc2@if33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP
    link/ether e2:a7:0f:d4:aa:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::e0a7:fff:fed4:aa1d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
40: vethf1238ff@if39: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP
    link/ether e6:1a:87:a4:18:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
    inet6 fe80::e41a:87ff:fea4:182a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
46: vethe334e2d@if45: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP
    link/ether a2:5f:2c:98:10:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
    inet6 fe80::a05f:2cff:fe98:1042/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
58: vethda32f8d@if57: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP
    link/ether ea:40:a2:68:d3:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 7
    inet6 fe80::e840:a2ff:fe68:d389/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
41596: veth9eddb38@if41595: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP
    link/ether fa:99:eb:48:be:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 9
    inet6 fe80::f899:ebff:fe48:beb0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
41612: veth161a89a@if41611: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP
    link/ether b6:33:62:08:da:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::b433:62ff:fe08:dac4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Just to be sure, when you try to access to the container via its internal IP, you use the port 8080 and not the 8084 right?

Comment: Correct, here is what we get (auth message is expected) `curl 0.0.0.0:8080/about
The resource requires authentication, which was not supplied with the reques`

Comment: So basically this works `curl 172.19.0.2:8084/about` and this doesn't `curl 172.31.105.59:8080/about`

Comment: Not quite, `curl 172.19.0.2:8084/about` works but `curl 172.31.105.59:8084/about` doesn't (both 8084).

Comment: Ok so that's the normal behavior of your container, the port mapping is usable only with the host IP. So 8080 with the container and 8084 outside because of your --publish

Answer (score 0):

Ok so that's the normal behavior of your container, the port mapping is usable only with the host IP. 
So if you use the container IP you have to reach the port 8080 (the real port of your application).

Because of the `--publish` you used, the port 8080 of your container is mapped to the port 8084 on your host IP

Comment: That's what is not working.  If I try to access 8084 on the host eth0 IP it does not work, however 8080 works within the container.